# What's the proper way to think about filepaths with a Flask application being served on apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: flask, apache2

I'm trying to allow users to download csv files from my flask app but in the route that handles file downloads from an ubuntu 18 server running Apache2.

```
import flask
import os
from io import BytesIO

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/<string:report>/<string:action>', methods=['GET'])
def report(report,action):
    if action == 'download': 
        files = os.listdir(os.path.join(basedir, f'static/reports/{report}'))
        filepath = url_for(f'static/reports/{report}/{files[-1]}')
        output = BytesIO()
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
        output.write(data)
        output.seek(0)
        return send_file(output,attachment_filename=files[-1], as_attachment=True)
```

But I'm getting this error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/reports'`

My Apache2 configuration already has an alias for Static files 
like so:

```
Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've also tried creating an alias for my reports folder under static but I still get the same results.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Why read the data into a `BytesIO()` object? `send_file()` would accept `filepath` *directly*, and serve the file more efficiently to boot.

Comment: Or use `send_from_directory()`, which takes a directory and filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is using `url_for()` to generate path. `url_for()` generates **URL** paths, not filesytem paths. You can't use the result to open a local file. `url_for()` is used to send the *browser* to a correct location.

You are serving files from the standard `static` path. Just leave figuring out where that is to Flask, the `app` / `current_app` object [has a `.static_folder` attribute](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.static_folder).

You also want to use the [`send_from_directory()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory) to serve the files directly. There is no need to first load the data into a `BytesIO()` object here. `send_from_directory` accepts a relative path as the second argument.

This should work:

```
@app.route('/<string:report>/<string:action>', methods=['GET'])
def report(report, action):
    if action == 'download': 
        files = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'reports', report))
        filename = files[-1]
        filepath = os.path.join('reports', report, filename)
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, filepath, as_attachment=True)
```

I omitted `attachment_filename`, because the default is already to use the filename of the file being served.

You may need to re-think the `files[-1]` strategy. `os.listdir()` produces files in an arbitrary order (whatever order the OS decides is most convenient). If you expect it to be the most recently created or modified file, you'll have to do your own sorting first.

Comment: Thanks! the ```static_folder``` explanation was very helpful.